# MEF DirectoryCatalog won't load, but AssemblyCatalog will

Tags: c#, plugins, dll, mef

I have a folder full of DLL, some of which implement my contract, and so I tried to load them like so:

```
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(this.dllFolder));
```

When it finds one of the DLL with my interface, it complains that it can't find get_Name in the DLL.  My interface defines a Name property with a getter and no setter, which the DLL does in fact implement.

Is there some trick to using properties with these catalogs?  As a temporary workaround I'm doing this, which does seem to work (and I'm able to access the Name property just fine from the rest of the code)

```
        var dlls = Directory.EnumerateFiles(this.dllFolder, "*.dll");
        foreach (var dll in dlls)
            catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.LoadFile(dll)));
```

Comment: Most probably the .dll is not being loaded by the DirectoryCatalog. MEF doesn't use Assembly.LoadFile. Instead it uses Assembly.Load. Most likely that's the difference between the two approaches.